# error with fb graph post image

Tags: iphone, facebook-graph-api, ios5, fb-graph

it will be just like repeated question on first look but it is not please read it till the end.

I can able to post images using the fb graph api.

1) I am able to post photos but it takes around **2 to 2.5 minites** 
   how to optimize it ie how to make it will take lesser time?
2) during the posting it give me nslog on ever 10 seconds like this

```
 void SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation*): delegate (webView:resource:didFinishLoadingFromDataSource:) failed to return after waiting 10 seconds. main run loop mode: _kCFURLConnectionPrivateRunLoopMode
```

how to code so i dont get this log?

My code for calling fb graph is from [this example](https://github.com/AalokParikh/iPhone-Facebook-Graph-API)

Comment: Where's the delay, is it because the photos are large files? if you resize the image client side before posting it is it still a problem?

Comment: i don't know how to re-size the images at client side? can you give me some guideline for it any link or any thing will be appriciated

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4394491/how-to-compress-resize-image-on-iphone-os-sdk-before-uploading-to-a-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok from the link or the question link given by @lgy i got the best working solution it is as below

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

thanks to @Tuan Nguyen who give the answer there i just repeat it as it helps me a lot 
and newSize is CGSize type variable
Happy Coding :)