# Image resizing with CIFilter?

Tags: objective-c, macos, core-image

Is it possible to resize image using CIFilter? I know `CILanczosScaleTransform`, but it resizes image maintaining proportions. And I need to resize image without maintaining proportions. How to do that?

Comment: http://gigliwood.com/weblog/Cocoa/Core_Image,_part_2.html

Comment: i think without maintaining proportions, best is to use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4394491/how-to-compress-resize-image-on-iphone-os-sdk-before-uploading-to-a-server

Comment: @NightFURy Your suggested solution is about resizing image maintaining proportions

Comment: @Prince Your suggested solution is about resizing image on iOS

Answer (score 4):

Why do you think `CILanczosScaleTransform` maintains proportions?
 CILanczosScaleTransform has a parameter @"`inputAspectRatio`" or `kCIInputAspectRatioKey` which allows you to scale *and* change the proportions. You can do it with

```
[filter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.7] forKey:@"inputAspectRatio"];
```

I took this from documents and didn't try it myself but am sure (due to my experiments with CIFilter) it works.

Comment: Note that `CILanczosScaleTransform` sets the output _height_ according to the `kCIInputScaleKey`. The output width is the input width multiplied by  `kCIInputScaleKey*kCIInputAspectRatioKey`.

Answer (score 2):

Use CIAffineTransform instead of CILanczosScaleTransform. Set a and d to your desired scale values. This will shrink or stretch your image to any proposition.

Answer (score 0):

All CIFilter is below. I suppose there is no filter to resize image.

- CIAdditionCompositing
- CIAffineTransform
- CICheckerboardGenerator
- CIColorBlendMode
- CIColorBurnBlendMode
- CIColorControls
- CIColorCube
- CIColorDodgeBlendMode
- CIColorInvert
- CIColorMatrix
- CIColorMonochrome
- CIConstantColorGenerator
- CICrop
- CIDarkenBlendMode
- CIDifferenceBlendMode
- CIExclusionBlendMode
- CIExposureAdjust
- CIFalseColor
- CIGammaAdjust
- CIGaussianGradient
- CIHardLightBlendMode
- CIHighlightShadowAdjust
- CIHueAdjust
- CIHueBlendMode
- CILightenBlendMode
- CILinearGradient
- CILuminosityBlendMode
- CIMaximumCompositing
- CIMinimumCompositing
- CIMultiplyBlendMode
- CIMultiplyCompositing
- CIOverlayBlendMode
- CIRadialGradient
- CISaturationBlendMode
- CIScreenBlendMode
- CISepiaTone
- CISoftLightBlendMode
- CISourceAtopCompositing
- CISourceInCompositing
- CISourceOutCompositing
- CISourceOverCompositing
- CIStraightenFilter
- CIStripesGenerator
- CITemperatureAndTint
- CIToneCurve
- CIVibrance
- CIVignette
- CIWhitePointAdjust

Comment: Can you explain how you created this list? I tried     NSLog(@"filterNamesInCategories %@", [CIFilter filterNamesInCategories:nil] );
and got much more filters. One of them was CILanczosScaleTransform which scales images.

Comment: This looks incomplete, or at least out of date. In iOS 6 there are 93 filters.

Comment: CILanczosScaleTransform available on OS X only. Not in iOS. He might have listed out from iOS.