# Images scaling, low res

Tags: ios, xcode, scaling

I am working with a menu and I need to create images which will fit in the 'cell'. Whenever I scale my image, it looks horrible!

[image: Still broken]

Code:

```
   CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(22, 22);  //whaterver size
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
    [cimg drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
  UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
         UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: Can you post code that performs the image scaling please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using another one of the techniques for resizing mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4394491/how-to-compress-resize-image-on-iphone-os-sdk-before-uploading-to-a-server).

If that does not satisfy your need, you might want to try looking at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6141298/how-to-scale-down-a-uiimage-and-make-it-crispy-sharp-at-the-same-time-instead)'s answer, [this](https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGImageUtilities) (very useful) MGImageUtilities' category, or [this](http://code.google.com/p/simple-iphone-image-processing/) library, to scale an image without losing quality.

Comment: I am having problems with the first library, it says it needs <vector>

Comment: I would try the code snippets in the linked S.O. question first.

Comment: and <stack> is being called too.

Comment: Sorry, S.O. stands for StackOverflow (this website).

Comment: Check out this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6141298/how-to-scale-down-a-uiimage-and-make-it-crispy-sharp-at-the-same-time-instead

Comment: Hmm. A little confused about the link.