# Lower the resolution of Videos - iPhone

Tags: iphone, video, resolution, alassetslibrary

Is it possible to lower the resolution of already taken videos/pictures? I need to export low resolution videos/pictures.

Answer (score 0):

U can use "scale" for it, i.e.: 0.5 for half-size

```
UIImage *ret = nil;
ALAsset *asset =[_assetImages objectAtIndex:page];
ALAssetRepresentation *defaultRep = [asset defaultRepresentation];
ret = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[defaultRep fullScreenImage] scale:0.5 orientation:0];
```

You should also look at Joshua Sullivan's answere on:
[How to compress/resize image on iPhone OS SDK before uploading to a server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4394491/how-to-compress-resize-image-on-iphone-os-sdk-before-uploading-to-a-server)

This changes the reported size of the scaled image, but does not actually change the image data. The data length of the NSData generated on the original and the scaled image is virtually identical.

Comment: But actually I need to lower the data size, so that upload process will be fast. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, with the answer of Sullivan. Just check the link.